# Is there an R function to summarise time-series values

Tags: r, time-series, average

I have a question that I can't answer myself even after searching for a while and for this reason I am hoping for a hint.

My challenge is that I have a time series that provides various other collected values as elements. The timestamps are stored in a column. In the other columns are the other values. The values are provided on a daily basis. Since I want to compare the values with another time series whose values are provided on a monthly basis, I want to summarize the values of the first table to average monthly values. I don't care if the values are added back to the original table or if a new table is created.

Many thanks in advance.

Update:

Unfortunately, the data is company data, so I cannot publish it. But maybe an example will help:

| Timestamp | Department | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | Procurement | 0.4 | 0.9 |
| 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | R&D | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | IT | 0.6 | NA |
| 1970-01-02 09:00:00 | Procurement | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| 1970-01-02 09:00:00 | R&D | NA | 0.3 |
| 1970-01-02 09:00:00 | IT | 0.9 | 0.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: You should be able to use `aggregate` to aggregate by month.. If you provided sample data, I would show you.

Comment: You can use `apply.monthly`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272

Answer (score 0):

You can create a month variable, and then *group by* and *summarise* the values

```
df %>% 
  mutate(month = month(Timestamp)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(.cols = c(Value1,Value2),.fns = ~mean(.,na.rm = T))
  )
```